# How to add scroll bar to existing powershell tables in an HTML Report with multiple dynamic tables

Tags: html, css, powershell

I have been banging my head against the wall for quite some time trying to figure this out, but I'm just stuck.

I've got a Powershell script that does a lot of data collecting on a server and then outputs into a reasonable looking HTML report using a collection of tables.  I've got no real issue with the data gathering parts of it, and you can see I've got just a simple building of the report using ConvertTo-HTML - Fragment.

What I can't figure out is how to add scroll bars to the tables when they're larger than say 300px.  I have tried to incorporate all sorts of tbody and div class lines of code, and I just cannot seem to wrap my head around how to get this to work like I want.

In a perfect world, I'd love my tables to be more like ones seen half way down the page here https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/scroll/ that are scrollable, searchable, and sortable, but I realized that was way beyond my knowledge right now so am content with just trying to get my tables scrolling for now because some of the tables, i.e. Services, Events, etc, just get too large and make the HTML Report way too long.

Here's a stripped down version of the script:

```
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$Timecheck = (get-date -format "MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm")
$Date = Get-Date
$htmlReport = @()
$htmlbody = @()
$htmlout = "$($ComputerName + "_" + $Timecheck).html"
$spacer = "<br />"

function HTMLCreate
{
    $htmlheader = @"
                    <style>
                    BODY{font-family: Arial; background: #eaf3dc; font-size: 8pt;}
                    H1{font-size: 20px; color: #5b8f22;}
                    H2{font-size: 18px;color: #5b8f22;}
                    H3{font-size: 16px;color: #5b8f22;}         
                    TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 8pt;table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; display: block; text-align:center; }
                    TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #5b8f22; padding: 5px; color: #ffffff;}
                    TD{border: 1px solid black; background: #d7e9bb; padding: 5px; }
                    </style>

                    <body>

                    <h1>Server Data: $ComputerName</h1>
                    <h3>Created: $Date by $User</h3>
"@

    $htmlend = "</body>"

    $htmlReport = $htmlheader + $htmlbody + $htmlend

    $htmlReport | Out-File $htmlout -Encoding Utf8
}



    $subhead = "<h2>System Information</h2>"
    $htmlbody += $subhead

    try
    {
        $SystemInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Name, Status, Domain, Manufacturer, Model

        $htmlbody += $SystemInfo | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
        $htmlbody += $spacer

        Write-Host " "
        Write-Host "     $ComputerName System Data Collection Complete.     " -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host " "
        Add-Content $LogFile -Value "`n$($Timestamp.Invoke())  -  $ComputerName System Data Collection Complete"

    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning "`n$($Timestamp.Invoke())  -  $ComputerName System Data Collection error encountered.  -  $($_.Exception.Message)"
        $htmlbody += "<p>System Data Collection error encountered. $($_.Exception.Message)</p>"
        $htmlbody += $spacer
        Add-Content $LogFile -Value "`n$($Timestamp.Invoke())  -  $ComputerName System Data Collection error encountered.  -  $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }




    $subhead = "<h2>Operating System Information</h2>"
    $htmlbody += $subhead

    try
    {
        $OSInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem | Select @{ Name = 'Operating System'; Expression = { $_.Caption } },
                                                                            Status, Version,
                                                                            @{ Name = 'Architecture'; Expression = { $_.OSArchitecture } },
                                                                            Manufacturer, Organization, InstallDate, WindowsDirectory,
                                                                            @{ Name = 'Last Boot Time'; Expression = { $_.LastBootUpTime } }

        $htmlbody += $OSInfo | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
        $htmlbody += $spacer

        Write-Host " "
        Write-Host "     $ComputerName Operating System Data Collection Complete.     " -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host " "
        Add-Content $LogFile -Value "`n$($Timestamp.Invoke())  -  $ComputerName Operating System Data Collection Complete"

    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning "`n$($Timestamp.Invoke())  -  $ComputerName Operating System Data Collection error encountered.  -  $($_.Exception.Message)"
        $htmlbody += "<p>Operating System Data Collection error encountered. $($_.Exception.Message)</p>"
        $htmlbody += $spacer
        Add-Content $LogFile -Value "`n$($Timestamp.Invoke())  -  $ComputerName Operating System Data Collection error encountered.  -  $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }


HTMLCreate
```

I appreciate any guidance.  I'm not savvy at all with how to incorporate css in Powershell and would like to keep this same basic script structure if I can.

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow: auto` to the CSS class of the table element?

Comment: I have tried that, and when added to TABLE section, it doesn't do anything.  Maybe because I'm not adding any height?  I have also tried many variations of placement for <div style="height: 300px; overflow: auto; ">, which depending on where I put it, does all kinds of changes, but none that I want.  Closest I got was the entire output of the script scrolling, rather than each individual table.

Comment: Try experimenting with adding height and perhaps `overflow-y: scroll`.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to set height of the entire table.  Thus far everything I'm trying is just setting the height of the rows within the table.  Will keep playing with it.